# Clojure projects worth reading?

Tags: clojure

The best way to learn a new language is reading well structured and well documented projects that use the language constructions in the proper way.

What are the best clojure repos to read and learn from them?

Comment: This may not be the best forum for your worthy question, since it is likely to generate opinion and discussion rather than solution. However, I'm glad you asked it.

Comment: Which should be the best forum? Thanks for your contributions

Comment: I've just found a [much better answer than mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2445054/1562315) to what is essentially the same question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clojure open source projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444893/clojure-open-source-projects)

Comment: @Thumbnail It is a duplicate of that question, but answers will be pretty different four years later. I'd rather close as opinion-based. Also, I don't really agree with the question's premise: the best way to learn a language is to *write code*. Reading is fine, but if that's all you do it's just a way to trick yourself into believing you're learning more than you are.

Comment: Yes, writing is the best way to learn, but sometimes you don't know what to write, or how to do it as the language 'requires', because each language has it's own slang that needs to be learnt... and the best way is to read quality code.

Comment: @fuzzyalej If I were you, I'd ask your question in the [Google Clojure group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/clojure).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. [Clojure itself](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/).
2. [Clojure in Small
   Pieces](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdaly.axiom-developer.org%2Fclojure.pdf&ei=7y2QU6iQJ4jb7AaQtIDIDw&usg=AFQjCNEb28ruYFvbIU51KhSarU4OhEGO0w&sig2=rzUbGFEzNShDIAqvRdm7eA&bvm=bv.68235269,d.ZGU):
   Clojure 1.2 as a literate program.

There's lots of advice [here](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/) and [here](http://dev.clojure.org/display/community/Contributing).

Thereafter, I would follow your nose. Find the stuff you are interested in: if it's good, enjoy it. If it's bad, do it better!

Be warned: Clojure is seriously addictive.

Comment: Thank you! CiSP seems a very valuable link! :)

Answer (score 1):

I often read https://github.com/aphyr (in particular https://github.com/aphyr/riemann). He writes a lot of Clojure and it's very often well documented and organized.

Others I crib from liberally:

- https://github.com/ztellman
- https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring